# Чем отличается мост от коммутатора?

Tags: сеть, потоки-данных, администрирование, маршрутизация, пакет

Хотел бы понять принцип работы коммутатора и чем он отличается от моста. Вопрос возник ввиду совершенно разных определений на разных сайтах, противоречащих друг другу.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что коммутатор - это устройство с
   несколькими портами, которое в отличие от концентратора может
   передавать сигнал на конкретный порт (концентратор может только
   повторять на все порты) благодаря таблице маршрутизации?
2. Тогда не пойму
   как у коммутатора происходит обучение (таблица маршрутизации), ведь
   пока на каждый из портов не будут отправлены данные, таблица полностью
   не заполнится? Это значит, что пока таблица не заполнится, все
   компьютеры сети смогут видеть, что я хотел передать только одному
   конкретному компьютеру (это вроде как небезопасно)?
3. Правильно ли я
   понимаю, что концентратор работает как аналоговое устройство -
   сигнал который передали он повторил и все? А коммутатор же как
   цифро-аналоговое - он сначала цифровым образом разбил на пакеты инфу,
   а потом уже по аналогу (кабелю) отправил в нужный порт (или во все порты, если идет обучение)?
4. Чем мост отличается от коммутатора?

Answer (score 5):

1. Да. Только это не совсем таблица маршрутизации;
2. Почитайте как работает протокол [ARP](http://citforum.ru/nets/tcpip/arp.shtml);
3. Да. Примерно так
4. Они соединяют сети на разных уровнях. Мост - более сложная железка - может сделать одну IP сеть с единым адресным пространством из разных сетей (в том числе удаленных друг от друга)

Мост соединяет сети на втором уровне. Но трафик между "концами" моста может идти через любые уровни. Мост анализирует сеть и собирает таблицу MACов отмечая какой физической сети они принадлежат. Получая пакет анализирует адрес получателя. Если этот адрес не принадлежит сети из которой пришел пакет мост передает его в другой интерфейс. Если получатель и отправитель находятся в одной сети мост игнорирует пакет. В современных сетях, наверное, самое распространенное применение в Wi-Fi точках доступа.

Comment: 4. Можно поконкретнее? Коммутатор не может сделать одну сеть IP с единым адресным пространством?

Comment: И что значит соединяют сети на разных уровнях?

Comment: Не может, так как он не работает с IP-адресами, а с MAC-адресами.

Comment: Тогда чем мост отличается от маршрутизатора, если тоже умеет работать с ip?

Comment: *чем мост отличается от маршрутизатора* Маршрутизатор обеспечивает передачу пакетов между разными IP-подсетями - при этом они могут существовать в одной физической сети (сегменте) или разных. Мост объединяет два разных сегмента, IP-подсети которых совпадают или различны (при этом в одном из сегментов необходимо наличие маршрутизатора между этими IP-подсетями).

Comment: Что не пойму, мост все-таки на третьем уровне работает раз может соединять в т.ч. IP-адреса? В википедии написано, что мост на втором работает, гонево?

Comment: Провод тоже соединяет, но он соединяет физически, и ничего про адреса не знает.

Comment: Мост тем не менее работает на канальном уровне, а это второй. IP- третий.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Дополнил ответ

Answer (score 4):

Коммутатор работает на втором уровне модели OSI ( подуровень MAC ), так как анализирует МАС-адреса внутри пакета 10( рис. [image: введите сюда описание изображения].). Естественно, он выполняет и функции первого уровня.

Маршрутизаторы работают на третьем уровне модели OSI, так как они анализируют не только MAC-адреса пакета, но и IP-адреса, то есть более глубоко проникают в инкапсулированный пакет 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача сегментации сети, т.е. разделения пользователей на группы (сегменты) в соответствии с их физическим размещением с целью уменьшения количества клиентов, соперничающих за полосу пропускания, была решена с помощью устройства, называемого мостом (bridge). Мост был разработан компанией Digital Equipment Corporation (DEC) в начале 1980-х годов и представлял собой устройство канального уровня модели OSI (обычно двухпортовое), предназначенное для объединения сегментов сети. В отличие от концентратора, мост не просто пересылал пакеты данных из одного сегмента в другой, а анализировал и передавал их только в том случае, если такая передача действительно была необходима, то есть адрес рабочей станции назначения принадлежал другому сегменту. Таким образом, мост изолировал трафик одного сегмента от трафика другого, уменьшая домен коллизий и повышая общую производительность сети.

Однако мосты были эффективны лишь до тех пор, пока количество рабочих станций в сегменте оставалось относительно невелико. Как только оно увеличивалось, в сетях возникала перегрузка (переполнение приемных буферов сетевых устройств), которая приводила к потере пакетов.

Увеличение количества устройств, объединяемых в сети, повышение мощности процессоров рабочих станций, появление мультимедийных приложений и приложений "клиент-сервер" требовали большей полосы пропускания. В ответ на эти растущие требования фирмой Kalpana в 1990 г. на рынок был выпущен первый коммутатор (switch), получивший название EtherSwitch.

Коммутатор локальной сети

Коммутатор представлял собой многопортовый мост и также функционировал на канальном уровне модели OSI. Основное отличие коммутатора от моста заключалось в том, что он мог устанавливать одновременно несколько соединений между разными парами портов. При передаче пакета через коммутатор в нем создавался отдельный виртуальный (либо реальный, в зависимости от архитектуры) канал, по которому данные пересылались напрямую от порта-источника к порту-получателю с максимально возможной для используемой технологии скоростью. Такой принцип работы получил название "микросегментация". Благодаря микросегментации коммутаторы получили возможность функционировать в режиме полного дуплекса (full duplex), что позволяло каждой рабочей станции одновременно передавать и принимать данные, используя всю полосу пропускания в обоих направлениях. Рабочей станции не приходилось конкурировать за полосу пропускания с другими устройствами, в результате чего не происходили коллизии и повышалась производительность сети.

Comment: Если используете чужие тексты, помечайте текст как цитаты и ставьте ссылки на источник. Иначе это плагиат.

Comment: И лучше своими словами, а то тупо скопировано и много воды.